# Proximity sensor on a service

Tags: android, service, event-listener

I am trying to start and proximity sensor service in my android app but the code simply just doesn't seem to work. The code runs the bounded comand also it runs the Localbinder. But still the app does not show the proximity sensor toast.

here is my code.

```
public class proxy_service extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mProximity;
    private static final int SENSOR_SENSITIVITY = 4;
    @Nullable

    public final IBinder b = new Localbinder();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.w("this","started");
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sevice on bind",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return b;
    }

    public class Localbinder extends Binder

    {
        proxy_service getservice() throws InterruptedException{

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sevice staaaaaarted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return proxy_service.this;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

        //mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mProximity,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sevice staaaaaarted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }



    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType() ==  Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY){
            if (event.values[0] >= -SENSOR_SENSITIVITY && event.values[0] <= SENSOR_SENSITIVITY) {
                //near
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "near", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //far
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "far", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mProximity,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }



    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Sevice destroyed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I have also registered my code in the manifest file

```
<service android:name=".proxy_service"></service>
```

and this is how i started my service in the mainActivity

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent i = new Intent(this,proxy_service.class);
        bindService(i, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        //startService(i);
        //Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            proxy_service.Localbinder binder = (proxy_service.Localbinder) service;
            try {
                c= binder.getservice();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        }
```

Comment: please clarify, what exactly `code simply just doesn't seem to work` means?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that you should `registerListener` when service started, not when `onSensorChanged` called since AFAIK `onSensorChanged` will be called only after you  `registerListener`

Comment: where should i register it? in main activity? or the service

Comment: in service I think. Try registering it right after creating it.

Comment: did it  work . .?

Comment: No it did't work...